# jquery auto select dropdown value

Tags: jquery

I am working within miva system so lets just say its a nightmare.  I have the following code that I have to work with

```
<select name="ShippingMethod">
<option value="mvfedexsoap:FEDEX_2_DAY">FedEx 2Day® ($15.91)</option>
<option value="mvfedexsoap:GROUND_HOME_DELIVERY">FedEx Home Delivery® ($13.36)</option>
<option value="mvfedexsoap:PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT">FedEx Priority Overnight® ($20.15)</option>
<option value="mvfedexsoap:STANDARD_OVERNIGHT">FedEx Standard Overnight® ($18.41)</option>
</select>
```

My only option within this store is to work with jquery.  I am fairly new to jquery so I would appreciate any help you are willing to give me.

On page load I want it to select the cheapest option. The method I was thinking of was to somehow collect the text within the option parse out the price then compare and select the lowest value. If you have something that may help I thank you ahead of time.

Comment: Are you in any way able to change the html? It would help you quite a bit if you could place the price in a data field. If this is possible I have a simple solution.

Comment: Miva does not allow you to edit this system

Comment: @James check my answer, improved version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/JeVV6/)**.

```
var idx = 0;
var lowest = 9999;
$('select[name=ShippingMethod] option').each(function(i) {
    val = parseFloat($(this).text().split('$')[1]);
    if ( val < lowest) {
        idx = i;
        lowest = val;
    }
});
$('select[name=ShippingMethod] option:eq('+idx+')').prop('selected', true);
```

​Basically this loops through the option text values, splits them and parses them into floating points, then finds the lowest value and selects it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("option").each(function(index) { 
 // alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text()); 
 var text = $(this).text();//get text for each option

  var price = text.split("$");//split text at the $ symbol

  var final_price = price[1].replace(/[()]/g,'');//remove all remaining parenthesis from string



  alert(final_price);

});
```

i quickly put this together which get the price on its own from each text so you can sort it. hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use using `.each` and those messy workaround, you can achieve what you need in 3 lines **;-)**

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/ZgEbH/

```
 prices = $("select[name=ShippingMethod] option").map(function(){ return parseFloat($(this).text().split('$')[1]); }).get();
 lowPrice = Math.min.apply(Math, prices);
 $("select[name=ShippingMethod] option:contains('" + lowPrice + "')").prop("selected", true);
```